# My pc shuts down while im rendering

Tags: rendering

I have a rtx 2060 ryzen 5 3600X but when im rendering a simple fortnote render with a little bit of lights my pc shuts down even when im rendering with only 20 samples
If anyone can help me

Comment: Did you try any other stress test or benchmark?

Comment: no i think but i think its the power

Comment: Hi :). This could be caused by CPU/GPU overheating. Not really a Blender specific issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about hardware issues